# VB.NET Dir() function get last written (most recent) file

Tags: vb.net, directory, filenames

I encountered a following problem.

I have a folder that may have a similar named files where only difference is the version of the file, as in "V1" or "V2" etc. And I always need to refer to the most recent one. I have written a code

```
FileName = Dir(ProjectsFolder & ProjectNumber & "_KDS_V*.xls*")
```

Where that "*" is the unknown element. In my case the version number. This code of mine get's the first file of such filename in directory, but I need the last one. I have also written a different code for programmatically opening the most recent file

```
Dim FileName As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo((IO.Directory.GetFiles(ProjectsFolder & ProjectNumber & "*_KDS_V*.xls*").Reverse)(0))
```

But I can't use this code as a string for my referring purpose.

Could someone, please, help me with the correct code for getting a string of the directory to the most recent file I am looking for?

Comment: Not at first, but at least this one let's me convert it .tostring so I can get the desired result. Thanks

Comment: you can store the path into a string when you create the file, and then you call the diagnostic start on that stringpath

Comment: @Eduards I don't understand...is there any reason why you can't use `file.FullName` as mentioned in the answer?